# Add facebook dependency gradle error

Tags: android, build.gradle

I add below dependency for `login with facebook` then error can show me.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
```

Below Error show me :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).  Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 27.0.2. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and
>   com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2 less... (Ctrl+F1)  There are
>   some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
>   incompatible, or can lead to bugs.  One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).

Gradle.build(app):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.+'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'

    //Volley
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    //facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'

    implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'


    implementation project(':revealfab')
}
```

Comment: Please post your gradel file code so we can help and this warning not regarding the Facebook API but regarding core android  API dependency.

Comment: Try with `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'` and let me inform.

Comment: Have you added the `mavencentral()` in your project level build.gradle ?

Comment: use `v7:27.1.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error is clearly mentioned that mixing lib versions is not a good idea (**mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes**), so don't that. Here you are using `7:27.1.1` and `7:27.1.+`. So keep the same version for all libs.

**Instead of:**

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)' // this is wrong
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.+'
```

**Use:**

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.35.0' //latest version and correct correct way
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: well i use your given dependency but same error are showing me

Comment: @MohammadAli please see updated answer. Hope it will help you

Comment: when i follow your update answer this error show me `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1`

Comment: @MohammadAli what error you are getting now? Can you try `Invalidate Cache/Restart`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177491/discussion-between-vicjordan-and-mohammad-ali).

Answer (score 1):

**Don't**

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
```

> One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android
>   support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a
>   version lower than your targetSdkVersion.

You should try with

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0' //4.35.0
```

For more details, visit [**`Facebook SDK`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/)

**FYI**

Use the **proper version**.

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Make sure, added

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

Comment: i follow your answer but not help for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may helps you

```
// Facebook Login only
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add below codes in Gradle of project-level:

```
ext {

    supportLibraryVersion = "27.1.1"

}
```

After that, add in Gradle of app-level:

1- Add same library version

2- Add following codes:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```